# How to prevent testcafe from restarting when being in --debug-mode and the browser did halt on a breakpoint

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I try to debug a little test client side with

```
   testcafe --debug-mode --dev Safari test1.ts
```

When the testcafe debug controls are shown I can inspect variables etc all fine.
However if I put a breakpoint in client side code and inspect variables if the browser execution is stopped testcafe restarts my test after some minutes and interrupts my debug session.

Is there a way to instruct testcafe to have infinite testing time for this scenario?
(I thought --debug-mode would imply that )

Answer (score 0):

At this moment, you cannot configure this behavior in TestCafe. However, TestCafe already has [an issue with this suggestion](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/2819), so you can vote for it. With more votes, there is a bigger chance that this feature will be implemented in the near future. Right now, you can debug your application under the TestCafe core using [`http-playground`](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe-hammerhead#first-look).